# How to make python cmdline module recognize that the argument is a String variable?

Tags: python, string, command-line

So I have the following code:

```
line = 'scrapy crawl backpage_tester -a start_url="' + url + '" -o ' + output
cmdline.execute(line)
```

And when I check what it is doing, it is literally running `line` as the command, when it should run the contents of the line variable.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thank you!

Module:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
```

Comment: What is `cmdline`?  It doesn't appear to be a standard module.

Comment: Sorry! I added it to my post.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354770/scrapy-pass-arguments-to-cmdline-execute

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I couldn't find that post. I appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354770/scrapy-pass-arguments-to-cmdline-execute